# Trying to get the currently selected item from a ComboBox DataTemplate inside a DataGrid off an DropDownClosed Event Handler

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate

I previously had a ListView that was displaying an ObservableCollection of "Player" object properties, which I'm trying to convert into a DataGrid. I have most of it working, but currently having some issues with seeing changes on one particular property (Status), which is represented by a ComboBox. The idea is to allow players to override the "Status" value between a set of enums representing things like "Alive, Dead, Poisoned," etc. I've hooked up an EventHandler for when the ComboBox is closed and inside that handler, try to grab the sender object as a Player so I can send out the valid player values.

Here's a snippet of the XAML where I'm creating the ComboBox via a DataTemplate.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Name="cbStatus" 
                      ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticResource statusTypes}}" 
                      SelecteItem="{Binding statusType, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      DropDownClosed="cbStatusType_DropDownClosed"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Inside the Event Handler, I'm using the following to try and grab an "Player" object based on the values coming back from that particular row of the GUI.

```
Player playerOverridden = (Player)(sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
```

However, when I'm debugging the new playerOverridden when the ComboBox closes and a new value is selected, I'm not seeing that value being captured in playerOverridden.

This is pretty much the exactly what I was doing in a ListView with GridViewColumn.CellTemplates and it was working just fine. Not sure why the Status value is coming back as whatever it was initially set to instead of what the player has selected from the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Had to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the `SelectedItemBinding` to be `PropertyChanged`, it works. Not sure why this has to be set explicitly inside a DataGrid where it's not something I needed to do in the ListView.

```
SelectedItem={"Binding statusType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```